# Prove that $P_{\text {match }}(G) \cap\left\{x: 1^T x=k\right\}$ is the convex hull of all matchings in $G$ of size exactly $k$.

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, polytopes, matching-theory

**Problem:** Prove that $P_{\text{match}}(G) \cap\left\{x: 1^T x=k\right\}$ is the convex hull of all matchings in $G$ of size exactly $k$.

**My attempt:**
Firstly, we prove that
$$\text{conv}\left\{\chi_M: M \text{ matching of size } k\right\} \subset P_{\text{match}}(G) \cap\left\{x: 1^T x=k\right\}$$
It is indeed, $x \in P_{\text{match}}(G)$. On the other hand,
$$1^T x = \sum_{M \text{ matching of size } k} \alpha_M \sum_{e \in E} \chi_M(e) = k.$$
Therefore, we attained the above inclusion relation.
For the inverse inclusion, there are two hints

- Explain why it suffices to prove the opposite inclusion for the extreme points.
- Let $x$ be a point of $P_{\text {match }}(G) \cap\left\{x: 1^T x=k\right\}$ and assume that the support of $x$ contains two distinct matchings $M$ and $N$. (Note that $M$ and $N$ need not be matchings of size $k$.) Consider the symmetric difference $M \Delta N$ and prove that $x$ cannot be an extreme point.

However, I did not understand the purpose and how to deal with the two above hints.

**Explanation for the notation in the problem:**

- $\text{conv}$ denotes for the convex hull.
- $\chi_M$ is a binary vector, i.e,
  $$\chi_M(e) \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{ if } e \in M\\
  0 & \text{ if } e \notin M
  \end{cases}$$
- $P_{\text{match}}(G) = \text{conv}\left\{\chi_M: M \text{ is a matching in } G\right\}$.

Comment: Please define terms and notation.

Comment: @MathieuRundström Thank you for your comment. I will do it